# Update binary column based on integer column - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I have some legacy data with a binary column, fish_otolith, that is not accurate. It should indicate based on separate column named fish_age. When an age is present in the fish_age column the binary column, fish_otolith, should indicate and when a null value is present in the fish_age column the binary column, fish_otolith, should not indicate.

| fish_otolith | fish_age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | Null |
| 1 | Null |
| 1 | Null |

I am struggling with writing the correct update sql statement of "if fish_age is not Null then fish_otolith is equal to 1, else if fish is null then fish_otolith is equal to 0

Comment: `update ttable set fish_otolith = case when fish_age is null then 0 else 1 end;`

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not store in the database something that can be calculated at run time (`fish_otolith` in your case).

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks for the response. this should do it but I get an error since the data type is stored as a boolean. How would I update based on the data type of boolean?

Comment: @mustaccio yes I know but this db is created so researchers can easily query the data with out too many join statements.

Comment: 1) No join needs to be involved and 2) you can create a view to make your researchers' lives easier.

Answer (score 0):

If your `fish_otolith` is a boolean, then try this:

```
update ttable 
   set fish_otolith = fish_age is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `fish_age is not null` returns a boolean value which can be cast as an integer with the result `false -> 0` and `true -> 1`, which is the results you are looking for. So:

```
update fishes  
   set fish_otolith = (fish_age is not  null)::integer;
```

This (or any other update) however contains a potential fatal flaw: `fish_otolith` can be updated independent of `fish_age` and can contain any valid integer not just 0 or 1. This con be overcome with a slight design change. Define `fish_otolith`  as a `generated always ...` derived from `fish_age`.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e509d4263e72248bec4bb02352e51c18) here - for both implementations).

Note: Either setting by @MikeOrganek would also work.